# Background image not rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a background image imported and trying to get it to render in the background of my component. Trouble is it does not render. I have checked the location and have tried using <`img ...>` and it renders perfectly fine. Unsure what i am doing wrong. My code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import MenuIcon from 'material-ui-icons/AccountCircle';
import LockIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Lock';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import Background from '../images/background.jpg';

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
  }

  updateUsername = (e) => {
    this.setState({ username: e.target.value });
  }

  updatePassword = (e) => {
    this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const centre = {
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '45%',
      left: '50%',
      marginTop: '-50px',
      marginLeft: '-100px',
      textAlign: 'center',
    };
    const background = {
      backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
      backgroundSize: 'cover',
      overflow: 'hidden',
    };

    return (
      <div style={centre}>
        <div style={{ backgroundImage: background }}>
          <Typography color="primary" variant="display1">REPORTS PORTAL</Typography>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: This is just a guess but i think backgroundImage requires quotes. backgroundImage: `url("${Background}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: background }}>
```

to

```
<div style={{ ...background }}>
```

In order to set the background's const properties as styles.

Comment: You can do <div style={background}> to skip the spread operator

Comment: great, that's another alternative!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
<div style={background}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: background }}>
```

to:

```
<div style={background}>
```

Style expects an object and you're wrapping an object within another object by including something you've already defined as an object within {}.  The only time you use {{ }} would be:

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`, backgroundSize: 'cover', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
```